# User Space sysfs

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, sysfs

I want to be able to create, read and write attributes in sysfs from user space.  I've tried this in a UIO driver (which supposedly runs in user space, so they say) but I came across the same issue with accessing sysfs from user space apps... no access to kobject, sysfs_create_*(), etc.

The sysfs is ideal for me to use to pull data from an IP stream and populate a virtual file system with information that can be exported using NFS.  Why?  The data is highly cooked for a very specific application I am developing.

I'm cross compiling from a Linux PC box to a Beaglebone board which is running Jessie.

Any recommendations?

Comment: What about just implementing a FUSE filesystem instead?

Comment: I looked into FUSE however there seems to be issues with exporting FUSE systems via NFS.  Unless something has changed (and I missed it), I don't think this is an option.